# Google Calendar Push Notification watch command in php

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I am using the php watch commant:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);


$channel =  new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel($client);
$channel->setId('20fdedbf0-a845-11e3-1515e2-0800200c9a6689111');
$channel->setType('web_hook');
$channel->setAddress('https://www.exampel.com/app/notification');

$watchEvent = $service->events->watch('primary', $channel);
```

This command works fine and I get the response:

```
Google_Service_Calendar_Channel Object ( [address] => [expiration] => 1401960485000 [id] => 20fdedbf0-a845-11e3-1515e2-0800200c9a6689111 [kind] => api#channel [params] => [payload] => [resourceId] => HZjSdbhwcd5KMKEA3ATA31LoR-w [resourceUri] => https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key=AIzaSyBl_Y7Y4eQDve-0DjwzBEP7_qOLo-67ouY&alt=json [token] => [type] => [modelData:protected] => Array ( ) [processed:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

However; In my set up url I don't get any message when something changes in my calendar.
Am I missing something!?

Comment: This is the only example of Google Calendar watch using google-api-php-client that I could find!

Comment: I know. I figured it out in my own how to use watch in google-api-php-client. The documentation was really bad. I hope it help you!

Comment: @IdealBakija Perfect example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue which was caused by authentication on my application.

Try sending a post request to `https://www.exampel.com/app/notification` and see if it is received. If not, double check your routing or authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Also ensure that the endpoint is a valid https URL. Self-signed certificates are not allowed.

Source: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push

Comment: Thanks for reiterating this. How did you go about testing this on a dev box (where the certs *are* typically self-signed)?

Comment: Very important: you also have to add your webhook in the Google console or it won't send notifications to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue today, so want to add some more details here.

Google only send the headers to your URL. so if you are waiting for getting some data (just like me) you won't get any (except some cases).

Check this [Google Calendar API docs for Receiving Notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#receiving-notifications)

> Understanding the notification message format
>
> All notification messages include a set of HTTP headers that have X-Goog- prefixes. Some types of notifications can also include a message body.

Here are the headers I received in my webhook callback URL.

```
[Host] => mydomain.com
[X-Goog-Channel-ID] => 10ddfddt0-a995-10f4-1254e2-0000000a0a0609001
[X-Goog-Channel-Expiration] => Thu, 11 Jan 2018 10:04:04 GMT
[X-Goog-Resource-State] => exists
[X-Goog-Message-Number] => 2526579
[X-Goog-Resource-ID] => 9OG_a-ECJycPkpNR1ZrWSon5_i1
[X-Goog-Resource-URI] => https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?maxResults=250&alt=json
[Content-Length] => 0
[Connection] => keep-alive
[User-Agent] => APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)
[Accept-Encoding] => gzip,deflate,br
```

I also found some [additional code sample here](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/1b24d82) which you can use if you want to make the request to Google API without client library.

Hope this help someone.